# Dynamic binding of multiple classes (Name of the class will come from some observable variable) using knockout css binding

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I am trying to use css binding of knockout, to bind multiple classes to one element. Some class names I know and those will be binded based on some conditions (which is working fine). Issue comes when I tried binding an observable variable(which will return me class names based on some conditions).

Here is what I have tried

```js
function vm()
{
  this.st = ko.observable();
  
  var data = true;
  var self = this;
  this.st(data);
  
  this.divColor = ko.pureComputed(function()
  {
    if(data == true)
      {
         return 'yellow';
        }
    else
     {
       return 'green';
       }
       
    });
                                  
  }
```

```css
.div1
{
  height : 40px;
  width : 50px;
  border : 1px solid black;
  }

.disable 
{
  border : 1px solid red;
  }

.yellow

{
  background-color : yellow;
  }
.green
{
  background-color : green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class = "div1" data-bind="css : {'disable' : ( st() == 1) , divColor : true'}">
  </div>
```

Also I have tried

```html
<div class = "div1" data-bind="css :divColor , css : {'disable' : ( st() == 1)}">
      </div>
```

But none of these is applying class, that 'divColor' is returning, to the element. First approach is adding 'divColor' as a class to the div element.

Any body have tried something like this before?

**I don't want to generate the classes, based on condition, from js and bind it, as same 'divColor' is used in multiple places with different classes based on conditions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of achieving what you want that comes to my mind is building the whole string value for the `css` binding, with all the classes that the element will have (check the snippet code). See that you will need to include also the classes that are static (like *div1*, otherwise they will be overwritten by the binding value).

```js
function vm() {
  var self = this,
      data = true;
  self.st = ko.observable(data);
  
  self.divColor = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if(self.st() == true){
      return 'yellow';
    }
    else {
      return 'green';
    }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```css
.div1
{
  height : 40px;
  width : 50px;
  border : 1px solid black;
}

.disable 
{
  border : 1px solid red;
}

.yellow
{
  background-color : yellow;
}
.green
{ 
  background-color : green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="css: (st ? 'disable ' : '') + divColor() + ' div1'"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @elbecita This is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To apply multiple css classes with knockout you either need to specify each css class separately with its own condition inside an object literal, or have an computed or pure observable return the classes that need to be applied depending on various conditions that you specify.

```js
function vm() {
  var data = true;
  var self = this;
  self.st = ko.observable();

  self.st(data);

  self.divColor = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if (self.st() == true) {
      return 'yellow disable';
    } else {
      return 'green';
    }

  });
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```css
.div1 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.disable {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="div1" data-bind="css : {yellow: st, green: !st(), disable : st}">
</div>
<div class="div1" data-bind="css : divColor">
</div>
<label>Has data: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: st" /></label>
```

Comment: I want to do it using knockout only.
Is it possible to do it without forming the classes from js @Nathan?

Comment: What do you mean knockout only? its all JavaScript in the end.  Just be careful that your html doesn't get so cluttered with adding knockout view configuration that it becomes too hard to understand. Sometimes its worth  putting a lot of the view state inside the knockout view-model that it makes the html easier to read and understand and to test the logic of your JavaScript.

Comment: I agree it can make html harder to understand, if al the conditions and classes will be added with css binding in HTML itself. If there are lots of classes to bind, with lengthy conditions, then, we should follow the answer that you gave. If it is only 2 or 3 classes, I think it's okay to add it in HTML directly with knockout css binding. @Nathan

Comment: Agreed. As always it comes down to the rock solid IT answer of "It depends"   8-)